# CSS and Javascript include error on Phonegap with xCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xcode, cordova

I have a huge problem with my Phonegap application. i have a basic options.html file which includes a CSS file and a JS file. The problem is that none of those two files are using by the HTML file. I already found out the solution with the External Host key, but i can't find it and it doesn't solve my problem to create it. I have also found out for the files rights.
Here is my code :

options.css (only the includes):

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/options.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/options.js"></script>
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: _The problem is that none of those two files are using by the HTML file_ - Sorry, don't take this the wrong way but it is not clear what your problem is, probably due to a language barrier. Could you try to explain it in a more clear way? Do you mean that some files are not being loaded by your page?

Comment: That's it. I would like (for example) to resize a button. It works perfectly on google chrome or firefox, but not on the iPad with phone gap. Those files are so not loaded by the page :)

Comment: Which files are not loaded exactly? If none of them are loaded, you need to make sure that your paths are correct. Perhaps try using relative paths (e.g. `./js/options.js` instead of `js/options.js`), maybe that will point at the files correctly. Also, the XCode debugger should give you some info.

Comment: The two files are options.css and options.js. I've already tried to use relative paths, and it didn't works...

Comment: Is Xcode showing any errors? Try looking at logs when you run the app in the simulator. Also, are you absolutely, absolutely sure they are linked properly in your project?

Comment: Xcode doesn't show anything. I'm absolutely sure for the links, it works with my index.html, with the same path as my options.html.

Comment: When you run it on Chrome or Firefox, are you using a wamp server (for example) ?
And maybe, can we have the folder tree ?

Comment: No, i don't use wamp or anything. My html files are in the www folder (the root), my JS files in www/js/ and my css files in www/css/ . Index.html loads correctly his proper files, but options.html doesn't

Comment: And if you try the path "/js/options.js" ?

Comment: It doesn't work either, for the two kinds of file.

Comment: Strange ... Have you try to delete all other include, just keeping the options.js, clear content of this file and just put an alert or something like that ?

Comment: I have some new stuff : I made like you said (just keeping the options JS and put a simple alert) and in my config.xml i change the content by the options.html ... And the alert worked. It seems finally to be a problem in my index.html. I won't take your time anymore for a new problem, thank you very much for your help !